# Slowly rotate an object in the z-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to slowly rotate an object in the z-axis?
I have an object at an angle z=0 and I want it to move to z=100.
How do I do it so it slowly rotates in like 5 seconds?

```
    public Vector3 rotationDirection;

    public float durationTime;
    private float smooth;

      void Update()
    {
        smooth = Time.deltaTime * durationTime;
        transform.Rotate(rotationDirection * smooth);
    }
```

rotationDirection should be from (0,0,0) to (0,0,20) however the rotation does not stop after reaching the angle. How do I stop it when it reaches (0,0,20)?

Comment: What have you tried? what problems did you have? what code do you already have?

Comment: I am sorry I did not try anything yet. Online its just rotating to face other objects but nothing to move from an angle to another.

Comment: Id have to advise you have a low googlefu skill as rotating objects is covered in many places

Comment: try these: [google unity c# rotate object over time](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+c%23+rotate+object+over+time&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE771DE771&oq=c%23+unity+rotate+ob&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i58j0l4.5815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you I have updated my code now

Answer (score 2):

Using Quaternion.RotateTowards did the work.

```
void Update()
{

Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, 20);
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 20f);

}
```